# Proxy request on firebase

Tags: json, proxy, header, cors, response

I have created a project using Ionic and deployed it as a PWA to firebase. I have got around CORS utilising a proxy to call google maps api sevices. This works locally however once deployed this is no longer the case.

The response I am getting on the server is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.l (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/vendor.js:1:312114)
at t.invokeTask (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
at Object.onInvokeTask (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/vendor.js:1:26996)
at t.invokeTask (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
at r.runTask (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/polyfills.js:3:16794)
at p (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/polyfills.js:2:27648)
at XMLHttpRequest.v (https://atomic-affinity-127705.firebaseapp.com/build/polyfills.js:2:27893)



"Http failure during parsing"
```

When looking at the text field I get the contents of my index.html page being parsed. Starting with the Doctype explaining why the error fails on <.

Ionic.config.json has the following:

```
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "https://maps.googleapis.com/"
  }]
```

and is called as such:
/api/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/ ....etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that are interested in this solution, I ended up utilising the js libraries provided by Google. The alternative to get around this is create a functions set on firebase and run express to do the calls for with the appropriate CORS headers however I didn't want to add extra calls in.